# Why does my return statement ignore the rest of my code in a function in python?

Tags: python

In my function, I type in a raw_input after my return statement and then I proceed to call my function. When I call my function the raw_input is totally ignored and only the return statement works.

```
    def game():
       #This selects 5 community cards from the pick_community function
        community = pick_community(5)
        card_4  = community[3]
        card_5  = community[4]
        first_3 = community[0:3]
        return first_3

        river = raw_input("If you are done with the round hit enter:" )
        try:
            if river =="":
                return card_4
        except:
            print "Dont cheat man"
            exit()
```

Comment: Why did you put `return` there? You told the function to *return*

Comment: Because that's what `return` does.

Comment: Every function is executed until the first 'return'.

Comment: The `return first_3` is the problem. A function execution ends after return statement

Comment: Please read about how and why to create a [mcve].

Comment: The code after `return first_3` wont be processed.

Comment: @PM2Ring first_3 is defined one line above.

Comment: @keksnicoh: Oops! So it is. :)

Comment: Why is `if river =="":  return card_4` inside a `try...except`? It will never raise an exception. BTW, you should generally not use an unnamed `except`, unless you know _exactly_ what you're doing.

Comment: @PM2Ring actually it *can* raise an exception... very improbable though :D

Comment: Just wondering, why is this question down voted so badly? I mean there is an attempt of code and the author - might be new to python - asked why this is not working.

Comment: @keksnicoh: I didn't downvote, but questions about fundamental syntax tend to get downvoted due to "does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That:

```
return first_3
```

returns and therefore ends the function.
The remaining code is just ignored, because you will never get past the return.

Answer (score 2):

Because a return statement gets out of the function, so the rest of the code wont execute

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return first 3 values and then continue in code you can do it using `yield`. It basically inserts values into generator, then in the end return the whole generator.

https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/
more here, or google for even more :)